# How can I split XML file into multiple XML so that every new file contains only one text node from the original one?

Tags: c++, xml, xslt, libxml2

I have a XML that looks like this (arbitrary XML input)

```
<NodeLevel1>
    <NodeLevel2>
        <NodeLevel3>
            Sample text 1
        </NodeLevel3>
    </NodeLevel2>

    <NodeLevel2>
        .
        .
        .
        ... <NodeLevelN>
                Some deep thought
            </NodeLevelN>
    </NodeLevel2>

    <NodeLevel2>
        Sample text 2
    </NodeLevel2>
    Sample text 3
</NodeLevel1>
```

What I would like to have after XSLT transformation is 4 new XMLs containing just a single text node like the following 4 XMLs:

1.

```
    <NodeLevel1>
        <NodeLevel2>
            <NodeLevel3>
                Sample text 1
            </NodeLevel3>
        </NodeLevel2>
    </NodeLevel1>
```

2.

```
    <NodeLevel1>    
        <NodeLevel2>
            .
            .
            .
            ... <NodeLevelN>
                    Some deep thought
                </NodeLevelN>
        </NodeLevel2>
    </NodeLevel1>
```

3.

```
    <NodeLevel1>
        <NodeLevel2>
            Sample text 2
        </NodeLevel2>
    </NodeLevel1>
```

4.

```
    <NodeLevel1>
        Sample text 3
    </NodeLevel1>
```

What is the best way to do that? I'm using C++ (I can use libxml2 and libxslt)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use XSLT 2.0 with `xsl:result-document` or in your case with libxslt you can also use the `exsl:document` extension element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="NodeLevel1/node()[self::* or self::text()[normalize-space()]]" mode="new-doc"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="NodeLevel1/node()" mode="new-doc">
  <exsl:document href="result{position()}.xml">
    <NodeLevel1>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </NodeLevel1>
  </exsl:document>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thinking about the problem a bit more I have improved the stylesheet to work with any kind of root element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*/node()[self::* or self::text()[normalize-space()]]" mode="new-doc"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*/node()" mode="new-doc">
  <exsl:document href="result{position()}.xml">
    <xsl:element name="{name(..)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(..)}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </exsl:document>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[edit]
If you want to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon or AltovaXML or XmlPrime here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*/(* | text()[normalize-space()])" mode="new-doc"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*/node()" mode="new-doc">
  <xsl:result-document href="result{position()}.xml">
    <xsl:element name="{name(..)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(..)}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Martin.
Sorry, I'm quite new to XSLT...
I'm trying to test your stylesheet but I'm failing... 
    `Warning: at xsl:stylesheet on line 6 column 34 of xsl.xml:
      Running an XSLT 1 stylesheet with an XSLT 2 processor
    Error on line 12 of xsl.xml:
      XTDE1450: Unknown extension instruction
      at xsl:apply-templates (file:/d:/users/../test/li
bxml2/xsl.xml#9)
         processing /SomeName/identifier[1]
    Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported`


I'm testing it with SaxonHE9.4N.

Comment: Well in your post you said you are going to use libxslt so I wrote a sample for that processor. If you want to use an XSLT 2.0 processor you can of course do that but then you will need to use a different stylesheet, I will post one now.

Comment: I'm going to use libxslt but I just wanted to test the sheet. I figured I can use Saxon to test it - sorry for my ignorance. Anyway, I was able to test your last snippet with Saxon and it worked just as I hoped it would. Now, if I understood correctly, I will have to use snippet number 2 for it to work with libxlst. Thanks, again Martin. This was a great and well elaborated answer!

Comment: There's a problem with the following input: 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
 <cd>
  <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
  <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Columbia</company>
  <price>10.90</price>
  <year>1985</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Hide your heart</title>
  <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>CBS Records</company>
  <price>9.90</price>
  <year>1988</year>
 </cd>
</catalog>`

What I expected here was 12 new XML trees (one for each text node), I'm getting only 2 (one for each **cd** node)...